# How to simulate navigation bar in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode

In xcode 8 we could simulate translucent navigation bar of a view controller. Is there a way to do the same thing in xcode 9?

I did the same thing as in xcode 8:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MokBd.png), yet nothing happens.

How could we manipulate navigation bar items if there is no navigation bar simulation?
Thanks.

Comment: The view controller must be embedded in a navigation controller

Comment: @MohamedMostafa root view controller is embedded in my case. I am referring to the view controller which is instantiated and shown from the root view controller.  This, second one, should also have a way of manipulating its navigation bar items.

Comment: FYI, this has been fixed in beta 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a bug that is going away in later releases but temporarily I just made controller root view controller of navigation controller. The navigation controller never gets instantiated or segued to from anywhere but it's enough to get storyboard to look correct.

Comment: In the end i went on doing the same thing. Whenever i need to manipulate navigation items i embed a view controller in a navigation view controller, and afterward i simply erase navigation controller and reconnect the segues (if i have any).
This has to be a bug in current beta releases (both beta 2 and 3).